# Dataview Delegate in Extension not executing

Tags: delegates, acumatica, dataview

I am attempting to provide a Dataview delegate overide to the UnionDeductions view in PRCalculationEngine.cs

I note that this View does NOT have a defined dataview delegate in the Base graph - and the declaration is a bit 'different' in that is uses a BQL Fluent class.

Is this even possible to introduce a data  view delegate in an extension
If so, Is there a different way of declaring the delegate ?

The business case is that the client needs to modify the Amount of the union deduction based on certain Employee attributes (length of service etc) and needs to dynamically modify the amount.

Due to the private and protected access of the GetBenefits and CalculateRegularBenefitNominalAmount methods, the only way I see to do this is to over-ride the dataview delegate and alter the Deduction/Benefit amounts prior to the calculation of the Benefit/Deduction amount...

public partial class PRCalculationEngine : PXGraph

{.....

public UnionDeductionQuery UnionDeductions;

...}

When I attempt to define a dataview delegate for this view in an Extension - I cannot get the dataview delegate to 'fire'
ie The code always just runs the .Select on the Base view but does not execute the delegate.

This is the core of the extension code
public class PRCalculationEngine_Ext1ESP : PXGraphExtension

{
public static bool IsActive() { return PXAccess.FeatureInstalled<FeaturesSet.payrollModule>(); }

```
    #region Select Overrides 

    public PRCE.UnionDeductionQuery UnionDeductions;

    protected System.Collections.IEnumerable unionDeductions()
    {
        foreach (PXResult<PREarningDetail, PRDeductionAndBenefitUnionPackage, PRDeductCode, EPEarningType> result in
            UnionDeductions.Select())

        {
```

// modify the package amount here...

yield return result;

```
        }


    }

    #endregion

}
```

This is how the view is being called in the Base Graph

foreach (IGrouping<int?, PXResult<PREarningDetail, PRDeductionAndBenefitUnionPackage, PRDeductCode, EPEarningType>> resultGroup in UnionDeductions.Select(deductionCode.CodeID)
.Select(x => (PXResult<PREarningDetail, PRDeductionAndBenefitUnionPackage, PRDeductCode, EPEarningType>)x)
.GroupBy(x => ((PREarningDetail)x).RecordID))
{

Any advice or observations would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If the requirement is to overwrite the logic of the base dataview delegate which also references other protected methods, try if this helps:

First create an extension of the base class as follows with the PXProtectedAccess attribute and the methods that you want to override:

```
[PXProtectedAccess]
    public abstract class PRCalculationEngine_FirstExt : PXGraphExtension<PRCalculationEngine>
    {
        [PXProtectedAccess]
        public abstract DedBenAmount CalculateRegularBenefitNominalAmount(
            PRDeductCode deductCode,
            PREmployeeDeduct employeeDeduct,
            PRPaymentDeduct paymentDeduct);
        
    }
```

Then create a second extension (your actual graph extension) inheriting from both the base class and the first extension you created above.

```
public class PRCalculationEngine_Extension : PXGraphExtension<PRCalculationEngine_FirstExt, PRCalculationEngine>
{

// Here declare the view, write the PXOverride method, and access the protected methods of the base graph by referencing those as Base1.CalculateRegularBenefitNominalAmount()

}
```

Note that the above snippets are just to give an indication. I have not really worked on the PRCalculationEngine or tested that code but had done similar changes on a different graph to override the dataview delegate. Let me know if it helps. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks Raj - I was using the abstract extension as you mentioned but it did not work. We decided to solve the user requirement in a different way. Turns out there is some default Acumatica settings around Union rates and Certified Jobs where we could handle this requirement without a customization.  thanks again..  Grahame